# Android emulator: How to monitor network traffic?

Tags: android, networking, emulation, traffic, sniffer

How do I monitor network traffic sent and received from my android emulator?

Answer (score 126):

There are two ways to capture network traffic **directly** from an Android emulator:

1. Copy and run an [ARM-compatible tcpdump binary](http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-binary-solo.html) on the emulator, writing output to the SD card, perhaps (e.g. `tcpdump -s0 -w /sdcard/emulator.cap`).
2. Run `emulator -tcpdump emulator.cap -avd my_avd` to write all the emulator's traffic to a local file on your PC

In both cases you can then analyse the pcap file with tcpdump or Wireshark as normal.

Comment: So it is not real-time/online? I mean, the packets can only be analyzed at the end?

Comment: In the first case, you could analyse via stdout on the device rather than writing to a file. In the second case, you may be able to stream/tail the file as it's written. Or you can capture network traffic on the host machine, rather than on the emulator.

Comment: I've found the emulators I use already now have tcpdump installed, and the command #1 works without installing one.  You can also run it with "adb -e shell tcpdump -s0 -w /sdcard/emulator.cap".

Comment: If you're using 2nd solution and you're getting `The -tcpdump flag is not supported in QEMU2 yet and will be ignored.` warning, add **-engine classic** to your command like this: `emulator -tcpdump emulator.cap -avd my_avd -engine classic`. This will force deprecated emulator engine, but should work until they fix the issue.

Comment: where the `avd` is located?

Comment: Where do I find `/sdcard/emulator.cap` in my host OS?

Comment: the link from the page about the tcpdump binary is broken, where to get the binary from now?

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes for pipe solution to analyze with wireshark in realtime

Answer (score 22):

It is also possible to use http proxy to monitor http requests from emulator. You can pass `-http-proxy` flag when starting a new emulator to set proxy (Example [burp](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)) to monitor Android traffic. Example usage `./emulator -http-proxy localhost:8080 -avd android2.2`. Note that in my example I'm using Burp, and it is listening port 8080. More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).

Comment: What about https traffic

Answer (score 16):

For OS X you can use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com), it's simple and easy to use.

For more information, please have a look at [Android Emulator and Charles Proxy](https://medium.com/@daptronic/the-android-emulator-and-charles-proxy-a-love-story-595c23484e02) blog post.

Comment: I don't know `Charles` before. But as far as I can see, it is HTTP-specific. But the OP's question is not.

Comment: Charles also exists for Linux, I have it installed on my Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 12):

It is now possible to use Wireshark directly to capture Android emulator traffic. There is an *[extcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/extcap.html)* plugin called *[androiddump](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/androiddump.html)* which makes it possible. You need to have a `tcpdump` executable in the system image running on the emulator (most current images have it, tested with API 24 and API 27 images) and `adbd` running as root on the host (just run `adb root`). In the list of the available interfaces in Wireshark (Qt version only, the deprecated GTK+ doesn't have it) or the list shown with `tshark -D` there should be several Android interfaces allowing to sniff Bluetooth, Logcat, or Wifi traffic, e.g.:

**android-wifi-tcpdump-emulator-5554 (Android WiFi Android_SDK_built_for_x86 emulator-5554)**

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, using AVD emulator. How do I install the plugin? How do I know if the emulator has tcpdump?

Comment: This worked out of the box with wireshark-qt 4.0.5 on Arch. Nothing extra to install. You need a "non google play" Image, as adb root will refuse otherwise

Comment: @CaptainCrunch there is a way to get root access on the "Google Play" emulators. I highly recommend this script, which makes the process seamless: https://github.com/newbit1/rootAVD

Answer (score 9):

Yes, wireshark will work.

I don't think there is any easy way to filter out solely emulator traffic, since it is coming from the same src IP.

Perhaps the best way would be to set up a very bare VMware environment and only run the emulator in there, at least that way there wouldn't be too much background traffic.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it's tough to get an emulator running on top of a VM.  Have you gotten this to work?

Comment: What issues have you run in to? I haven't done it myself, but I can't imagine there would be any issues.

Comment: In my case, the requests being sent were in green, all I did was shut down other browsers and I was able to spot the sweet green rows.
Once you spot the request, copy the destination address and u can then use it in filter by putting ip.dst == "ip address that u copied" and seeing only the relevant requests.

Answer (score 6):

A current release of Android Studio did not correctly apply the `-tcpdump` argument.  I was still able to capture a dump by passing the related parameter to qemu as follows:

```
tools/emulator -engine classic -tcpdump dump.cap -avd myAvd
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

> Steps:
>
> 1. Install Wireshark.
> 2. Select the network connection that you are using for the calls(for eg, select the Wifi if you are using it)
> 3. There will be many requests and responses, close extra applications.
> 4. Usually the requests are in green color, once you spot your request, copy the destination address and use the filter on top by
>      typing `ip.dst==52.187.182.185` by putting the destination address.

You can make use of other filtering techniques mentioned [here](https://linuxhint.com/filter_by_ip_wireshark/) to get specific traffic.

Answer (score 6):

While Android Studio's App Inspection's **Network Inspector** menu is helpful for tracking network requests, I've noticed that it doesn't track all requests. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler).

The easiest way to track network requests for the android emulator that I know and use is [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/). It really quick to set up, and has a nice UI (similar to Chrome Dev Tools' Networks tab) for tracking the requests.

Just install it, click on the "*Android device via ADB*" option, and accept the prompts shown in the emulator ([docs](https://httptoolkit.com/docs/guides/android/)).

[image: HTTP Toolkit UI]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to monitor http traffic:

http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/

You can also use Fiddler2 [here](http://mrrask.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/setting-up-the-android-emulator-for-http-debugging-using-fiddler2/).

Comment: Another link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/04/03/configuring-fiddler-to-be-a-proxy-for-android-emulators.aspx).  I would add that the proxy server should be `10.0.2.2` which is the host machine's IP address in Android emulators, no need to find out what it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can monitor network traffic from Android Studio.
Go to Android Monitor and open Network tab.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

**UPDATE:** ⚠️ Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1. See more in https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Comment: can you tell from where to open detail network usage tab in android studio 1.5 (windows) as shown in image in the link, I am only getting  a graph but not details?

Comment: Be aware that this option gives limited insight. I couldnt solve my problems where I want to find out why a request was denied, because Android didnt tell me anything about this request. Fiddler is more suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

You can start the emulator with the command `-avd Adfmf -http-proxy http://SYSTEM_IP:PORT`.
I used HTTP Analyzer, but it should work for anything else. More details can be found here:
http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/04/intercept-http-requests-sent-from-app.html

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/install.html

Its easy to setup and won't require any extra tweaks.

I go through various tool but found it to be really good and easy.

Comment: I don't know `mitmproxy` before. But as far as I can see, it is HTTP-specific. But the OP's question is not.

Comment: New Android Studio 3.0 provides profiler, you can use that. And for mitm it provides all kind of protocols, http, https etc. You just need to configure the proxy correctly.

Comment: Is it available to capture packets from apps not developed by me? And on a 3rd party emulator such as Nox App Player? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should have the mitm certificate installed on your emulator/device, which is provided by mitm itself, and you can use this to watch the ongoing request and corresponding responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think running the traffic through an HTTP proxy is the best solution.

One of the main problems I encountered when trying to connect a MITM HTTP proxy to an Android emulator was inspecting SSL traffic.

Installing a root certificate on an emulated device was more trick than I expected.

One of my colleagues created an updated step-by-step guide on [capturing SSL traffic on an emulated Android device](https://www.loadmill.com/blog/behavior-driven-mobile-testing).