# HTTPResponse debugging with the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to know if there is anyway to debug the HTTP response with the android emulator. my logs show that the response is not arriving complete to the application and i would like to know if it is the server that does not send the complete response or if my application is not processing the response completely.

I tried hooking up Fiddler and Blurp proxy, it actually works with Blurp proxy but only for HTTP and as you may guess i need it also for HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer regarding capturing network traffic on the emulator:
[Android emulator: How to monitor network traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453949/android-emulator-how-to-monitor-network-traffic/2574493#2574493)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup TCP/IP Monitor within eclipse. Then point your android emulator to talk to your computer and to the port you setup the monitor to listen on. The monitor will then forward the request to the appropriate host (which you configure when you create the monitor). This works nicely for your problem ;)

Take a look at [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.monitor.ui.doc/topics/rwtcpvw.html)