# Can I listen the HTTP contents in Android like the wireshark

Tags: android, http, wireshark

I work the requirement to listen the content in the http stack at Android,
Like the wireshark. So I search related Content about this, but there are nothing,
So Can really listen the contents, if yes, how?
Thanks

Comment: are you looking for an app that functions like Wireshark, or are you trying to create your own app with this functionality?

Comment: I want to create own app with this functionality.

Comment: There's already an Android app on Google Play that does exactly that, called [Shark for Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark), which dumps TCP traffic into Wireshark format.  Do you have a real (ahem, non-evil) reason to recreate this functionality?

Comment: Thanks Drew. Because this requirement is so crazy, It want to analyze user's http contents, so I must recreate this function and add our special functions to analyze.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555403/capturing-mobile-phone-traffic-on-wireshark/9570093#9570093 you can also re-direct your browser traffic through an http proxy as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794998/how-to-configure-an-http-proxy-like-fiddler2-or-charles-web-proxy-with-the-lates