# Using Wireshark or Fiddler to study Android app without using emulator

Tags: android

when I would like to study the network activity of an 3rd party application on desktop

- How do this application send GET request?
- What parameters are POSTed by this application?

Wireshark or Fiddler will come in very handy.

Now, there is a 3rd party application installed in my Android phone. I also like to perform similar study on it, just like I did on desktop's.

I came across this tool https://sites.google.com/site/androidarts/packet-sniffer

I haven't tried it out as I do not root my phone yet. But from what I can see from screen shoot, it may not be something what I am expecting. I am expecting I can get a **view of network request and respond text content**. But the tool is just showing network hardware ID, IP address and number of bytes information.

I saw one way to study the Android network activity is to use emulator + Wireshark.

[Android emulator: How to monitor network traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453949/android-emulator-how-to-monitor-network-traffic)

But, the 3rd party application which I intent to study is installed in my real android phone only. Is there anyway I can get something similar to Wireshark/ Fiddler output, by running the targeted app on real phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Share a wifi connection and run Wireshark on your computer.

Comment: Do you mean they should just be on the same wlan? I just tried and I can't see any requests originating from the phone. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use estrongs file browser to backup the app first, offload it to your pc over usb, and then install it on the emulator via adb install .apk

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en