# eclipse monitoring network traffic of android

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to monitor the network traffic in Android, but I don't know how to make this.
How can I monitor the network traffic in Android in Eclipse?

Comment: Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453949/android-emulator-how-to-monitor-network-traffic

Comment: I had already seen, but the FIDDLER only runs on windows. I need a solution for linux.

Comment: If you only want to watch the network usage of your app (not the device or emulator network usage as a whole) you can use http://tools.android.com/recent/detailednetworkusageinddms coming with SDK tools r17

Comment: it looks pretty good, but still does not serve because serving only to android 4 or +

Comment: The answer given by @207 is your only option for monitoring network traffic in Eclipse. Perhaps you should consider expanding your interest to cover non-Eclipse options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently heard of the PCAP Web Performance Analyzer that is supposed to be able to do this.  I have not tried it myself yet, but it sounds like it might capture the data you're interested in.  It does not have Linux-specific instructions, but it looks like you might be able to capture your traffic on the command line and upload to the PCAP site for analysis.

PCAP upload site: http://pcapperf.appspot.com/)

PCAP for mobile devices (linked from the above URL): http://code.google.com/p/pcaphar/wiki/CaptureMobileTraffics

Hope this helps...