# tool to monitor the urls sent by the android application

Tags: android, networking

I am working on an android application which will request data from the server.

And now I want to monitor the `http urls` sent to the server just like what I can do by the firebug.

So I wonder if there is any tool that can meet my requirements?

Comment: This is a bit vague. What do you want? Do you want the output to the log? Or do you want to capture the whole request? If it's the latter you probably want to set up a proxy like Charles in your machine and go through that.

Comment: Just like the `network` panel in the firebug, I want to know what urls are sent and what are responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you are on an emulator, you can [run the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453949/android-emulator-how-to-monitor-network-traffic?rq=1) with the `tcpdump` flag to get the dump on your PC.

```
emulator -tcpdump emulator.cap -avd my_avd
```

If you are on a physical devices, consider setting up a HTTP Proxy, and use Wireshark on the Proxy.