# Capturing network traffic from Android Emulator

Tags: android, macos, http, wireshark

In order to debug my Android application I need to take a closer look at the HTTP requests my app produces. For that purpose I have set up Wireshark on my Mac.

For testing I opened up a browser. All traffic appears fine in Wireshark.

Outgoing requests from the Android emulator however do not appear! But strangely I can see the servers' responses...
Why are all outgoing requests invisible?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453949/android-emulator-how-to-monitor-network-traffic

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem as well. It drove my crazy, but eventually I found out what went wrong by filtering over TCP traffic instead and noticed this strange protocol in Wireshark, Elasticsearch. So I googled it, and this is what I found:

> 9200 - TCP HTTP RESTful interface
>
> 9300 - TCP Binary API and inter-cluster communications

And the server I send my requests to were using port 9300. So thats why I did not show any HTTP requests even though my  emulator received the response.

**To sum up**: Check if ur server connecting to is using port 9200 or 9300 and change it.