# How to perform mobile app packet analysis?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, analysis, packet

I've written a an app and I'm having issues finding a solution to tcpdump data from the Android device running said app.

**Android:**

The only solution I've found is to root your phone (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/analyzing-android-network-traffic--mobile-10663). Although this is not always possible. ***There needs to be a way to perform analysis via adb or Android Studio.* *Unfortunately I have not found a way to do that.***

Additionally I've tried PCAPdroid which is an app. This does not seem to be giving me all of the packets I expect to see.

**iOS:**

Apple provides a feasible solution to create a virtual interface with a connected device where you can then tcpdump all traffic leaving said device.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/recording_a_packet_trace?language=objc

Comment: If physical device is not a requirement. See: [How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5095234/295004)

Comment: Physical device is not a requirement. I will try this option and report back. Thank you.

Comment: Turns out the steps provided are outdated and not useful. Still looking for feasible approach to simply perform packet analysis on my android application. @MorrisonChang thank you for the idea

Comment: And neither the [adb root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67172015/295004) or [magisk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65953362/295004) answers from this year apply/worked?

Comment: Perhaps covering the obvious: [Android emulator: How to monitor network traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2453949/295004)